# Understanding Cpython garbage collection generations

Tags: python-3.x, garbage-collection, cpython, python-internals

I am trying to improve my understanding of how memory management works in python and I am confused about the concept of generations in pythons garbage collector module.

My understanding is as follows:

All objects created start in generation 0, once a threshold (700 by default for gen 0) is reached python will run a collection on that generation and any surviving objects age into the next gen.

Given the above, I cant understand the below output.

```
import gc
import sys
x = 1
print(gc.get_count())
gc.collect()
print(gc.get_count())
```

Output

```
(64, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 0)
```

Firstly, I've only run 1 line of code and Ive already got objects in gen 1 and 2 implying that garbage collection has already occurred at-least twice, how is this possible? Is there anyway to find out what objects are in each generation?
Secondly,
Why do I have 0 references in all generations after collection? I can still run the command `print(x)` and not get an error. Doesn't this mean there is still a reference to x and so it should exist in one of the generations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gc.get_count()` shows you the counter for each generation, towards the threshold.

It is **not** the amount of objects in each generation, but the counter, that when it reaches the threadshold, the collection will occur for that generation.

For example, if I start with `(0,0,0)` on the counter, running `x = [[] for i in range(100)]` will set the counter to `(101,0,0)`.

Running `y = [[] for i in range(600)]` will cause the counter to flip to `(0,1,0)` and `gen0` collection will run. At this point all of my lists will move to `gen1` as they survived a `gen0` collection.

When counter reaches `(699,699,0)` and another object is allocated, `gen0` and `gen1` collection will happen and the counter will go to `(0,0,1)`. When counter reaches `(699,699,699)`, and an object is allocated, **or you use `gc.collect()`** (which runs `gen2` collection), counter will reset back to `(0,0,0)`.

To get the objects in each generation use `gc.get_objects(gen)`.

Regarding the garbage collection before your code runs - when Python starts, it creates lots of objects, before even loading your script. For example, you can see the modules that were loaded by running `sys.modules`. When those objects are created, the garbage collector runs automatically.